Why does specific heat capacity of iron reported by NIST-JANAF significantly exceeds the one predicted with Dulong–Petit law?
According to the Dulong–Petit law, the heat capacity for a unit volume approaches $3R$ for temperatures much higher than the Debye temperature. For instance, the specific heat capacity for iron for constant volume is ~ 25 J/K/mol at very high temperatures.
However, according to NIST-JANAF Themochemical Tables, the heat capacity of iron has been recorded to be ~ 40 J/K/mol at 1800 K. How is this so? What am I missing out on?

At such high temperatures, electronic excitations as degrees of freedoms may play role too. Like for molecules of halogens, where heat capacity gets higher than 7/2R as theoretical maximum without excitation.

The electronic excitation due to electrons contributes only a small amount to $C_v$ even at 2000K, about $\approx$ 1 kJ/mol/K as the Fermi level is filled so only electrons from approx $k_BT$ below this can be involved. However, there are numerous phonons that can be excited and should add to the heat capacity as the temperature increases.

There is more magnetic ordering below this temperature, I guess.
